# Freeing a structure containing void *

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I came across this code implementing a queue

```
typedef struct Node {
    void        * data;
    struct Node * next;
} node_t;
```

the node is free'd in this way

```
static void freeNode(node_t *node) { free((void*)node); }
```

Why is the node casted to `void *`?
Should't have been just `free(node)`?

And since I'm working on another structure :

```
typedef struct TaskNode {
  void (* fun)(void *);
  void * arg;
  struct Task * next;
} task_t;
```

Should I cast the pointer to the malloc'd structure to `void *` too before freeing it?

Comment: If you were in C89, and had not included `stdlib.h`. then `free((void *)node);` would be correct and `free(node);` incorrect .  But those days are behind us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast is useless in this context, c auto-promote any pointer to `void *` in a lot of context(not for stdarg for exemple):

```
free((void*)node);
```

is equivalent to:

```
free(node);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are quite correct that casting to `void*` is gratuitious. And as it doesn't clarify anything for fellow programmers either, it shouldn't be there.

Naturally, that's the case for both examples.